# Disable Wordpress Visual Composer Auto format

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have tried this codes but the `<p></p>` and `<br>` tag still appears.
Is there any other way to remove/disable this?

```
function my_formatter($content) {
$new_content = '';
$pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
$pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
$pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
        $new_content .= $matches[1];
    } else {
        $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
    }
}

return $new_content;
   }    

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```